# Possibly poor rails design - I need some advice to make a customized controller more CRUD like

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have little experience in rails and web-development in general. I think what I have here is bad design from what I've been studying . I don't think I'm using a rails way of doing this since this is an upload file functionality, how can I make it like the familiar CRUD style. I created a custom controller called `FileUploadController`. I also have a custom class called `FileProcessorService`
User will navigate to the `upload` page which has the multipart form button to select and upload the file. The `import` action is what gets called when the submit button on the multipart form is clicked.

```
<div class="row">

<h1>Upload File</h1>
    <%= form_tag({action: :import}, multipart: true) do %>
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
<%= submit_tag("Upload and Tabulate", :class => 'button', id: 'upload_button') %>
<% end %>
```

Can this be railsified? How can I make this design like a familiar CRUD like controller? It wasn't exactly obvious to me on how to do that since this is upload file functionality. Thank you in advance.

```
   class FileUploadController < ApplicationController

       def index
       end

       def import
         initialize_processor(params[:file])

         if (@file_sample != nil || @index_name != nil) then
           render 'index'
         end
       end

       def upload

       end

       def initialize_processor(file_in)

         File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', file_in.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
          file.write(file_in.read)
         end


        @file_processor = FileProcessorService.new(file_in)
        @file_sample = @file_processor.present_data_sample()
        @index_name = @file_processor.load_index()
      end
end
```

Comment: Are you going to want them to be able to look at the file once it's uploaded too? and maybe change the file for a different one or delete it?

Comment: Couple of things: 1) `initialize_processor` should be in the `protected` section since it's just a helper rather than an action. 2) if you rename import to 'create' you just got more cruddy :)

Comment: Yea I want users to be able to see contents of the file (csv file btw). But I want to remain on the same page where the upload form is and display some total counts and aggregates based on some columns as the file is being uploaded. Could the File be considered a Model object? Should I be thinking like that in terms of designing this thing? Because its not really crud until the file name is stored into the database. Each user can be associated to multiple files.